# SHA256 on Linux 4.4 embedded real-time system

Tags: security, real-time, embedded-linux, sha256

I am currently working with a real-time embedded system using custom Linux 4.4.115 provided by our vendor. Out of the box, it supports MD5 hashing, but we have a requirement of SHA256. The hashing is purely for user account login.

I was able to install OpenSSL on the box. I can create the SHA256 hash of a password but I am unsure about how to set it as a user account password. I've tried putting the hashed password in /etc/passwd but that obviously doesn't work. So after research I discovered I need to put it in the /etc/shadow file. This file does not exist on this system which means the Shadow package is not installed.

I went to install the Shadow package but I've run out of space. Is there anyway that I can use this SHA256 password without the /etc/shadow file? Recompiling the kernel is a last resort, we'd like to avoid that.

Comment: *"the Shadow package is not installed*" -- You've probably analyzed the situation incorrectly.  Doesn't your *"embedded system"* use Busybox?  The use of **/etc/shadow** is a configurable option in Busybox, e.g. **FEATURE_SHADOWPASSWDS** and **USE_BB_SHADOW**.  IOW you probably need to reconfigure and build Busybox rather than *"install the Shadow package"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly you might have to just recompile the kernel so you can get the shadow package. From experience and all the research I'm seeing online I don't see any other way of storing the SHA256 user passwords without the /etc/shadow file path. Obviously if you're root you can `$ sudo passwd user` to change / set the user passwords to the hashed SHA256 passwords but the only place that I'm seeing them ever stored is the /etc/shadow file.

The only reason I say that is because the only way I know of verifying the data for the user passwords is `pwck -r /etc/shadow` & `pwck -r /etc/passwd` so without those file paths I don't see any other way of storing / verifying the user password data.

Have you tried the `pwconv` command to create the /etc/shadow file from the /etc/passwd file?